# Dynamically pass parameters to DSC resource?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I was working on a composite resource when I came across the issue of being able to dynamically pass parameters to a DSC resource and wondered if there's another way to tackle this that I'm missing.

Basically, I have the an array (Below) that contains one PSObject per desired file-share. Each of these PSObjects has properties that are used as parameters for my DSC resource (In this case the [cLocalFileShare](https://github.com/SNikalaichyk/cLocalFileShare) community resource).

The issue is, not all of these objects have all of the parameters defined. For example, some of my shares don't have any users/groups assigned to the `ReadAccess` permission, but in my `ForEach` loop (Below), a `$null` value is being passed to the actual resource as this permissions isn't defined, and this causes the resource to error as it is trying to set `ReadAccess` permissions to user `$null`.

My issue is, how do I tackle this - for this resource and others?

- I've tried splatting the parameters in the DSC resource, but this doesn't seem to be supported. If this worked, I could build a different parameter list and pass that.
- Somebody on Reddit suggested passing a string that contained all of the parameters, but again this doesn't seem to be supported.
- **My worst fear is, I will have to edit each resource to support (and ultimately ignore) $null values which seems like a really bad way to tackle this.**

---

So, here's my array containing a PSObject per file share.

```
$MyConfig = @(
    @{ 
        Path = 'D:\Shares\Accounting'
        Name = 'Accounting'
        Ensure = 'Present'
        ChangeAccess = 'AccountingAdmins'
        ReadAccess = 'AccountingInterns,FinanceDepartment'
    } 
    @{ 
        Path = 'D:\Shares\Software'
        Name = 'Software$'
        Ensure = 'Present'
        ReadAccess = 'DomainUsers'
    }
)
```

Now, within the actual DSC configuration...

```
configuration {
    ForEach ($ShareProperties in $MyConfig) {
        # Each resource is named after the Path specified, but with the colon replaced as that's not valid character for the resource name
        cLocalFileShare $ShareProperties.Path.Replace(':','__') {
            Path = $ShareProperties.Path
            Name = $ShareProperties.Name
            Ensure = $ShareProperties.Ensure
            ChangeAccess = $ShareProperties.ChangeAccess
            ReadAccess = $ShareProperties.ReadAccess
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody have any ideas? /r/Powershell has failed me also...

Comment: You should be able to pass the array to the composite resource and have it iterate through the array.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution.  But you could use a conditional section within your ForEach loop.

```
configuration {
ForEach ($ShareProperties in $MyConfig) {
    # Each resource is named after the Path specified, but with the colon replaced as that's not valid character for the resource name
    if ($ShareProperties.ChangeAccess -eq $null) {
        cLocalFileShare $ShareProperties.Path.Replace(':','__') {
            Path = $ShareProperties.Path
            Name = $ShareProperties.Name
            Ensure = $ShareProperties.Ensure
            ReadAccess = $ShareProperties.ReadAccess
        }
    }
    else
    {
         cLocalFileShare $ShareProperties.Path.Replace(':','__') {
            Path = $ShareProperties.Path
            Name = $ShareProperties.Name
            Ensure = $ShareProperties.Ensure
            ChangeAccess = $ShareProperties.ChangeAccess
            ReadAccess = $ShareProperties.ReadAccess
        }     
    }
}
}
```